# How are the National Express coaches from London to Cardiff?

Tags: uk, public-transport, london, buses

Planning a trip from London to Cardiff using National Express coaches.   Compared to rail they are very cheap, but I'm wondering about the comfort.

In the past I experienced issues with where to to put my legs during the trip.
I'm curious whether there is enough space to sit, since the trip is about 4h.

Comment: I voted to close this because this is opinion based. A more factual question would be the seat pitch for the coaches National Express uses but I do not think there's a standard across all of their vehicles. Beyond seat pitch, there's lumbar support, seat height, headrest... comfort is complicated.

Comment: Also check Megabus - it may be cheaper, especially if you book in advance.

Comment: They're OK as long as you don't get some behemoth in the next seat. If you're taller than 1.80m you won't find the leg room generous.